# Common Source JFET amplifier input voltage

Tags: resistance, voltage-divider, jfet, formula-derivation

I want to compare to different formulas which stand for same parameter/value.

Here is common source JFET amplifier circuit schematic:

[image]

Here is the first formula which should apply in general to all BJT and unipolar transistors: [image]

, where Rin - input resistance (usually considered as voltage divider), Vsig - signal/generator voltage and Rsig - signal/generator internal resistance.

And here is another formula that applies for only for common source jfet source degeneration configuration: [image]

, where Vgs - gate-source voltage, gm - channels transconductance and Rs - source resistor

Which one is correct for common source JFET?

To me it seems to be more correct the fist formula since the input signal is attenuated a bit if I'm not wrong, so in every case input voltage is a bit smaller that gate-source voltage, right?

Comment: Formula 1 applies to a **voltage divider**. **ANY** voltage divider. It does not matter if it is near a BJT, JFET or an elephant. It applies to a voltage divider.

Comment: I could draw several circuits where formula 2 would apply, also it is unrestricted to JFET, MOSFET or BJT. There's a gm in there so it can apply to any device with a "gm", even a Valve. I could name any resistor Rs so that does not limit the application of that formula either.

Comment: Perhaps you should learn how to derive the formulas **from a given schematic**, you have asked questions about this before and it was explained in the answers to these questions. Trying to fit formulas to schematics will become more easy when you get more experience with the circuit to formula procedures. My advise is to forget about what you're asking here and concentrate on deriving formulas from schematics and not the other way round.

Comment: @FakeMoustache: Good point. But the only way to verify those derived formulas is by applying them to practical examples and through measurement?

Comment: Before measurements I suggest to first try to **confirm** the formulas in a circuit **simulator**. In a simulator it is much easier to control everything and there are less pitfalls like oscillations, noise, no broken transistors. In a simulator you can use any value component you like, no non-idealities etc. The proper way (to analog design) is to first start with **theoretical analysis**. 1) you find the formula 2) you **confirm** it in the simulator.  3) (optional) you measure it. But for simple circuits, there is no real need to measure except learning how to do a measurement.

Comment: @FakeMoustache: One more question: Vin=Vgs right (approximate)? So Vin is the signal measured between signal output nodes and Ugs is the voltage drop across the gate to source junction?

Comment: *Vin = Vgs (approximately)* Is it ? Why ? Because Vin and Vgs are not in parallel. There's C1 and Rs//Cs. If Vin = 1 V DC, will Vgs also be 1 V DC ? If Vin is 1 V AC, will Vgs be 1 V AC ? If the frequency of that AC signal is very low or very high, now what happens ? You're again looking for **universal truths** like: I can **always** assume that.... But then one day you **will** fall into a trap because then a situation will pop up when you **cannot** apply that "universal truth" so your assumptions will be wrong. Always **think** about assumptions, when are they valid.

Comment: @FakeMoustache: I will try to. I am just curious about this one thing - Vout = Av x Vin - so Vin is the voltage amplitude of the generator and generator only?